# How to get a value from a child razor page back to the parent razor page

Tags: razor-pages, asp.net-blazor

I'm trying to learn blazor. I've created a Blazor Server application. I have a parent razor page that references and child razor component. I need some help or understanding.

In the parent I reference the child component 'Cities' like this:

```
<Cities selectID="selCities" CityList=@cities></Cities>
```

This passes 2 parameters to the child. the childs html looks like this:

```
<select ID="@selectID" class="form-control col-3">
    @if (@CityList != null)
    {
        @foreach(var city in CityList)
        {
            <option value="@city">@city</option>
        }
    }
</select>
```

This works great and provides a populated dropdown list box with an ID and options.

However, how do I reference the selected text from the parent component?

The child component will reside in an InputForm on the Parent. When the Save button is clicked, I need the text value of the select box from the child component.

I know it would be simpler to just keep the select on the parent, but I'm trying to learn to build reusable code. and this is just an exercise. I know there will be many times I need to return a value to the parent component. Just cant figure it out.

Thanks Much!

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer researching more thoroghly.

It appears that you can create a callback event in the child components code that will update the parents components values.

For other who are searching, I found this information here:[Share Data Between Child And Parent Components In Blazor](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/share-data-between-child-and-parent-components-in-blazor/)